# Render dueling buttons as "active" in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Using the RStudio tutorial on [dueling button](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html), I've setup a data toggle. One of the buttons is default and so should look "active" when the page loads (with inward shadow). After clicking on the other button, the "active" state needs to switch between the two buttons.

Is it possible to implement this with Shiny?

Comment: Why don't you use a tablet panel? This has exactly such an active/passive behaviour.

Comment: I could do that, but I'm already using tabs for a different purpose and would prefer to have a toggle button than another row of tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the cleanest way, but it definitely gets the job done. Got the bootstrap classes [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-options):

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    uiOutput("camera_one"),
    uiOutput("camera_two")
  )),
  server=shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

    v <- reactiveValues(btn_class_c1 = NULL, btn_class_c2 = NULL)

    observeEvent(input$btn1, {
      v$btn_class_c1 <- "btn-primary"
      v$btn_class_c2 <- "btn-default"
    })

    observeEvent(input$btn2, {
      v$btn_class_c1 <- "btn-default"
      v$btn_class_c2 <- "btn-primary"
    })  

    output$camera_one <- renderUI({
      actionButton("btn1", "Camera One", class=v$btn_class_c1)
    })

    output$camera_two <- renderUI({
      actionButton("btn2", "Camera Two", class=v$btn_class_c2)
    })

  })
)
```